# Counterfeit Money

Tags: checking-account, sugar-daddy, counterfeiting

I had a sugar daddy deposit 4500 in my account . By my debit card wasn’t working . So I called the bank they Lomé my account was blocked & to call the fraud center . My bank is pretty good at this stuff . So I called & she said to me that he was paying me with counterfeit money ? What does this mean for me ? This was the first time I’ve ever had a sugar daddy or ever been in this situation

Comment: You have been scammed. Take this as a lesson that nothing in life is free.

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean for me ?

It means you were the victim of a scam. The person you have been talking to intended to take advantage of you financially, or use you to take advantage of other people. If you want to know the details of how these scams typically work, you can search this site for "sugar daddy" - or wait for people to close your question as a duplicate - since there have been many similar questions.

In the end, if you are left wondering what you should do, you should discontinue all communication with this person and follow your bank's instructions. Make sure you understand your bank's policies and don't do anything that puts you at risk - don't give any personal information to anyone, and don't give anyone else access to your account.

If this person deposited the money by accessing your account directly (i.e. you gave them your username and login to your online banking account), make sure your bank knows that, and change your password immediately. If you have given this person any other details about your bank account, let your bank know, and follow their directions.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, if this was on-line, how does the scammer manage to deposit counterfeit money?

Comment: There are lots of ways to put money in an account online. A paypal transfer, an ACH transfer, a wire, a mobile check deposit, or many other types of "on-line" transactions that credited the account. A common scam mechanism in these scenarios is the scammer asking for the target's online banking info, then the scammer logs in and links to an external account to transfer money, or they use a mobile check deposit function to deposit a bogus or stolen check.

Comment: Yes, I know about all of those (or many of them, at least).  But the question is about COUNTERFEIT money.  That is, actual physical currency.  Seems like detecting and linking it to the "sugar daddy" would have to be done when he tried to deposit those bills in his bank, so the money would never have gotten further down the chain.

Comment: @jamesqf Frankly, I suspect the bank didn't actually say "counterfeit", or used counterfeiting as an analogy to explain why the payments bounced.